# grouping coordinates within a distance to each other

Tags: python-3.x, list, pandas, nested-loops

I have written this code which works but takes a very long time (~8hrs) to finish execution.

Wondering if it can be optimized to execute quicker.

The aim is to group a lots of items (x,y,z) coordinates based on their distance to one another. For example;

I would like to group them for a distance of +-0.5 in x, +-0.5 in y and +-0.5 in z, then the output from the data below would be `[(0,3),(1),(2,4)...]`.

```
        x     y     z
0  1000.1  20.2  93.1
1   647.7  91.7  87.7
2   941.2  44.3  50.6
3  1000.3  20.3  92.9
4   941.6  44.1  50.6
...
```

What I have done (and which works) is described below.

It compares the first row of the `data_frame` with the 2nd, 3rd, 4th .. until the end, and for each row, if the distance from `x to x < +-0.5 and y to y < +-0.5 and z to z < +- 0.5` then the index is added to a list, `group`. If it doesn't then it compares the next row until reaching the end of the loop.

After each loop is complete the indexes which matched (stored in `group`), are added to another list, `groups`, as a set and then removed from the original list, `a`, and then next `a[0]` is compared and so on.

```
groups = []   
group = [] 
data = [(x,y,z),(x,y,z),(etc)] # > 50,000 entries

data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x','y','z'])

a = list(i for i in range(len(data_frame)))

threshold = 0.5

for j in range(len(a) - 1) :
    if len(a) > 0:
        group.append(a[0])
        for ii in range(a[0], len(data_frame) - 1):
            if ((data_frame.loc[a[0],'x'] - data_frame.loc[ii,'x']) < threshold) and ((data_frame.loc[a[0],'y'] - data_frame.loc[ii,'y']) < threshold) and ((data_frame.loc[a[0],'z'] - data_frame.loc[ii,'z']) < threshold):
                group.append(ii)
            else:
                continue
        groups.append(set(group))
        for iii in group:
            if iii in a:
                a.remove(iii)
            else:
                continue
        group = []
    else:
        break
```

which returns something like this, for example;

```
groups = [{0}, {1, 69}, {2, 70}, {3, 67}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7, 9}, {8}, {10}, {11}, {12}, 13}, {14, 73}, {15}, {16}, {17, 21, 74}, {18, 20}, {19}, {22, 23}]
```

Have made many edits to this question as it was not very clear. Hopefully makes sense now.

Below is an attempt using better logic 'O(NlogN)' which is much faster but doesn't return the correct answer. Have used the same +-0.5 for x,y,z.

Edit:

```
test_list = [(i,x,y,z), ... , (i,x,y,z)]

df3 = sorted(test_list,key=lambda x: x[1])

result = []
while df3:
    if len(df3) > 1:    ####added this because was crashing at the end of the loop
        a = df3.pop(0)
        alist=[a[0]]
        while ((abs(a[1] - df3[0][1]) < 0.5) and (abs(a[2] - df3[0][2]) < 0.5) and (abs(a[3] - df3[0][3]) < 0.5)):
            alist.append(df3.pop(0)[0])
            if df3:
                continue
            else:
                break
        result.append(alist)
    else:
        result.append(a[0])
        break
```

Comment: it's a little unclear what you're trying to accomplish here. Could you explain the filter you are trying to apply to the data?

Comment: the filter is just checking proximity to one another, it's not the actual one there, it's just been simplified. The aim of the script is to find which rows are close to one another based on their values, so if row 1, row 2, row 5 and row 2000 have an 'a1' value that is within the threshold, then a list will be created with [1,2,5,2000] in. This will then be removed from the original list, and the next iteration will start with comparing row 3.. and so on.

Comment: at least provide a sample DataFrame with data we can use, please, with expected results

Comment: Please provide some sample inputs and expected outputs. Even a small number of rows from your DataFrame would make it much clearer.

Comment: You may want to add an argument `columns=('a1', 'a2', 'a3')` to your sample. Would make it easier to work with...

Comment: Also, `a = list(i for i in range(len(data_frame)))` is just `a = list(range(len(data_frame)))` or probably just `a = range(len(data_frame))`

Comment: The outer loop needs to be a `while` loop because `range(len(a) - 1)` is generated only once, but you call `a.remove` inside the loop.

Comment: Can you describe clearly, in words, what you are actually trying to accomplish? You've confused things by describing the algorithm you are using, which you yourself admit is sub-optimal, but not the actual desired end-result.

Comment: aim is to group items based on their proximity to one another.

Comment: have updated the question, hopefully makes more sense now!

Comment: How are you defining "proximity" to one another? Euclidian distance? All corresponding points must be within a tolerance? (I suspect you mean this one, which is pretty easy by sorting your data). Only some points need to be within a tolerance? Its impossible to answer your question without you telling us what you mean: give us a *specific* rule that determines if two points should be grouped or not.

Comment: consider them as x,y,z coordinates and their proximity to one another. so if (x1,y1,z1) is within 0.3m of (x2,y2,z2), then the rule is satisfied.

Comment: @matman9 Your last comment and your comment on chrisckwong821's answer disagree with each other. Chris's answer is checking if all of the point's coordinates are within +-5 (if you used 0.3, this would be maximum distance away of sqrt(0.3^2+0.3^2+0.3^2) ~= 0.52). Please clarify what you are actually asking for. If you truly want distance between points, (ie: [Euclidian distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) ) then your problem is much harder and needs a very different answer.

Comment: I'm trying to find a more efficient/quicker method to check the distance between points, or the Euclidian distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are comparing each data point with every other one, your implementation has a worst time complexity of O(N!). A better way is to do a sorting first.

```
import random
df = [i for i in range(100)]
random.shuffle(df)
df2 = [(i,x) for i,x in enumerate(df)]
df3 = sorted(df2,key=lambda x: x[1])

df3
[(31, 0), (24, 1), (83, 2)......
```

Assuming now you want to group number that are +5/-5 into one list. You can then slice number into list based on a condition.

```
result = []
while df3:
    a = df3.pop(0)
    alist=[a[0]]
    while a[1] + 5 >= df3[0][1]:
        alist.append(df3.pop(0)[0])
        if df3:
            continue
        else:
            break
    result.append(alist)

result
[[31, 24, 83, 58, 82, 35], [0, 65, 77, 41, 67, 56].......
```

Sorting takes O(NlogN) and a grouping basically takes linear time. So this would be much faster than N!

Comment: One point to note, your original implementation has no unique solution since you remove the data once it is grouped. So the grouping would be changed once you change the starting point. But once you sort the list, the grouping is guaranteed to be unique. You can also customized the condition  to be dynamic comparison if you want an implementation similar to [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN).

Comment: this is exactly what i was hoping for! thanks. i've tried this in my code and get a different final output to the original code. don't think that i follow the while loop properly. all i've done is replace the filter and added some extra values to the data, so instead of (i,x), is now (i,x,y,z), and the filter is sorting for i, +5/-5 x, +5/-5 y, +5/-5 z. i'll update the question with more info.

Comment: When u have x,y,z, you would need to specify the grouping requirement, do you want to group them if any of x,y,z is within +/-5 or all of them are within +/-5? i would recommend you to implement with one element first and, add in the others when u get through the logic

Comment: yeah, would be all of them. so do you mean, group them by x, then y, then z, and then combine them at the end? so have result_x, result_y and result_z, and then result_xyz if result_x in result_y and result_x in result_z?

Comment: yeah, so if you want to be inclusive you need to rank them strictly, by x, then by y, then by z, but actually this is quite tricky, for example you have (1,2,3) and (0,3,2). Ranking x first would put (0,3,2) in front, but when you rank y if becomes the opposite. So ranking three component is not a going to be perfect. Do you know euclidian distance? computing the euclidian distance is a good way to measure multidimensional distance.

Comment: only from the comments above. i'll try that next. I have actually managed to implement what you suggested and it now runs in a fraction of the time (~8hrs to ~3mins), so thanks! the code can be refined but it works and gives (almost) identical results. basically sorted for x, then groups for x, then the output of that is sorted for y (in the x groups) and then grouped for y, and then for z.